# Display string html content in aspx page

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a string HTML text saved in a `string` variable. for example it looks like this:

**sample.aspx.vb**

```
Dim htmlStr As String = "<h1> Hi </h1>"
```

I want the `htmlStr` variable's content formatted as a HTML tag and displayed in the `aspx` page. How can I do this ?

It should look like this:

**Hi**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple drop in a control on the form you want to use. A plaine jane "div" is fine, or even a label works. (a text box will not).

So, say I drop in this div (and a button)

```
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="test button" />
        <br />

        <div id="mycooldiv" runat="server">

        </div>
```

Now, code behind can be this:

```
Protected Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Dim htmlStr As String = "<h1> Hi </h1>"

    mycooldiv.InnerHtml = htmlStr

End Sub
```

and now we get/see this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

A LiteralControl can contain HTML.

```
    Dim htmlStr As String = "<h1> Hi </h1>"

    Me.Controls.Add(New LiteralControl(htmlStr))
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.literalcontrol?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: Still it doesn't get displayed on the UI. Is there another code block that I require to insert in the ASPX page ?